# echo'ing commands (with returns) into Popen stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I'd like to run an fdisk function in python, but the returns are making this not work...

```
command = ['echo', '-e', "'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw'", '|', 'sudo', 'fdisk', '/dev/xvdm']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

This gives the the (incorrect) output of:
`b"'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw' | sudo fdisk /dev/xvdm\n"`

What is the equivalent?

Comment: Quotes in `echo -e 'foo'` are for the shell's consumption. When you're passing an explicit argv list and using `shell=False`, there *is* no shell to consume them, so they're literal. Same for the `|` -- it's an instruction to the shell; if there is no shell, there's nothing to follow that instruction.

Comment: See the [replacing shell pipelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) section in the popen documentation, for cases where you actually *did* need a pipeline.

Comment: That said, `echo -e` should never be used -- the only interpretation of black-letter POSIX spec is that `echo -e` *must* print `-e` on output; any shell that doesn't do so is noncompliant. (Bash is noncompliant *by default*, but becomes compliant if the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options are set, so even if your shell is bash, it isn't safe to make assumptions about what `echo -e` will do). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly, the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just run `fdisk` and send it the input yourself?

```
command = ['sudo', 'fdisk', '/dev/xvdm']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a pipe (|) in a command like this. The pipe is given as argument to the program ("echo" in your case).

scnerd give you the best way/answer to send input text to fdisk.

If you really want to keep the pipe, you shall run a "bash" program with argument "-c" (command), and give in parameter the command (including your pipe) :

```
command = ['bash', '-c', "echo -e 'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw' | sudo fdisk /dev/xvdm"]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: If you changed it from `echo -e` (a bashism when doing anything other than printing `-e` on output) to `printf` (standard-mandated functionality), you could set `shell=True` and avoid the need for `bash -c`.

Comment: Yes good comment. It is better with shell=True, for exemple:
command = ["echo -e 'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw' | sudo fdisk /dev/xvdm"]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, ... , shell=True)

Comment: With `shell=True`, your shell is `/bin/sh`, so `echo -e` is not guaranteed to work. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html -- the POSIX standard for `echo` itself suggests using `printf` instead, if using backslashes in format strings, or `-n`. (`-e` isn't mentioned at all, as the black-and-white text of the specification doesn't permit it to have any special behavior; see "implementations shall not support any options" in the header up top; the only exception to that is specified for `-n`, which makes behavior undefined when passed as the first operand).